# Solution for open gallery in multi devices?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I'm developing a camera app. I have many issues when handling camera & gallery. The same code but not the same result if I run on different devices. Of course, this is not a permission problem. I've had set permission (CAMERA & WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) in code for API >= 23.

For example, I have 2 ways to open gallery

(1)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivity(intent);
```

(2)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(imageUri)), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

With Oppo, I can open Gallery by both 2 ways, but with Mi4C, Sony XA1 I can not. Neither way work.

With SKY, I can only open Gallery with (1)

So what is the best solution for opening Gallery in multi devices? How can I ensure it works for ALL devices without testing on them?

Comment: can you post your error log from `logcat` whenever error occures?

Comment: you must check permission in android >= 6.0

Comment: it does not have any log :(

Comment: you should use libs: https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher

Comment: @Nguyễn Trung Hiếu: I have checked permission for API >=23. I also mention it in my post